# Is mean deviation the same as mean absolute difference?

Tags: terminology, dispersion, mean-absolute-deviation

Do both  terms mean the same thing or are they different?

Answer (score 8):

Mean deviation is the same as mean absolute **deviation**; it is mean deviation from the mean. 
$$
MAD=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}|x_i-\overline{x}|
$$

Mean absolute **difference** is for two independent values $X$ and $Y$
$$
MD=E[|X-Y|]
$$

Comment: I couldn't comprehend the second formula notations (namely "E" and square brackets use). Can you help?

Comment: it's expected value of variable, you can read a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) for some information.

Comment: @ankit see [Mean absolute difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_difference) on Wikipedia for an equivalent equation for mean absolute difference that may be more comprehensible. $$\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} |x_i -y_j|$$